# How to GMT date convert into MM/dd/yyyy using java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

Here, I attached my code and finally I get the date in string format (ex: 1). But I want it for date format (ex: 2)
Ex:1

```
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.text.DateFormat; 
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

 public class Example{     
 public static void main(String []args){        
 java.util.Date date = new Date("Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017");               
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");              
 String formatz = formatter.format(date);           
 System.out.println(formatz);     
}}
```

The O/P is:

```
12/01/2017 // String so i cant able to parse it on my query.
```

Ex:2

```
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.text.DateFormat; 
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

 public class Example{     
 public static void main(String []args){        
 java.util.Date date = new Date("Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017");               
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");              
 String formatz = formatter.format(date);  
 Date d1 = formatter.parse(formatz);        
 System.out.println(d1);     
}}
```

The O/P is:

```
Sat Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT 2017 // but i want 12/01/2017 (date format)
```

how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(d1));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.  You should always use the appropriate class in the `java.time` package instead.

Now, onto your question.  Neither `java.util.Date`, nor any of the `java.time.*` classes, contain information about formatting.  They contain simply enough information to represent the moment in time.  If you want to use a different format from the default, you will need to use either a built-in formatter, or your own.

In your case, because `formatz` already has the format you want, you can simply print that instead.